# edit data in bootstrap modal via php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I've got a basic bootstrap-table displayed. When I click on a cell, I'd like a modal to open with the deviceId of that row, and the results of the "function" cell. If there is nothing in the "function" cell, the modal would still load and allow me to enter data for that cell.  Once the modal is open, I'd like to either edit and then save the data, or cancel.  I've reviewed several of the other questions asked on this forum, but none seem to have the answer.  The modal loads, but there is no data there to edit. The correct data is being returned via php (I can see this in Firefox' console), but nothing is displayed).

Here is my table:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
        
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="table-responsive">
            
                <table class="table table-responsive table-striped" 
                    id="scandata"
                    sortName="deviceId"
                    sortOrder="desc"
                    data-toggle="table"
                    data-detail-view="true"
                    data-detail-formatter="detailFormatter"
                    data-filter-control="true"
                    data-pagination="true">
                    <thead class="table-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th data-name="deviceId" data-field="deviceId" data-visible="false">ID</th>
                        <th data-name="hostname" data-field="hostname_id" data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="input" data-align="center">Hostname</th>
                        <th data-name="ipAddr" data-field="ip_id" data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="input" data-align="center">IP</th>
                        <th data-name="macAddr_id" data-field="macAddr_id" data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="input" data-align="center">Mac Address</th>               
                        <th data-name="openPorts" data-field="openPorts" data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="input" data-align="center">Open Ports</th>               
                        <th data-name="network" data-field="network" data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="input" data-align="center">Network</th>               
                        <th data-name="status" data-field="status" data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="input" data-align="center">Status</th>               
                        <th data-name="functionData" data-field="functionData" data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="input" data-align="center">Function</th> 
              
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                <?php
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  ?>
                            
                        <tr>

                        <td><?php echo $row["deviceId"]; ?></a></td>
                        <td data-type="text" data-abc="true" data-pk="<?php echo $row['deviceId']; ?>"><?php echo $row["hostname"]; ?></td>
                        <td data-type="text" data-abc="true" data-pk="<?php echo $row['deviceId']; ?>"><?php echo long2ip($row["ip"]); ?></td>
                        <td data-type="text" data-pk="<?php echo $row['deviceId']; ?>" data-abc="true"><?php echo $row["macAddr"]; ?></td>
                        <td data-type="text" data-pk="<?php echo $row['deviceId']; ?>" data-abc="true"><?php echo $row["openPorts"]; ?></td>
                        <td data-type="text" data-pk="<?php echo $row['deviceId']; ?>" data-abc="true"><?php echo $row["network"]; ?></td>
                        <td data-type="text" data-pk="<?php echo $row['deviceId']; ?>" data-abc="true"><?php echo $row["status"]; ?></td>
                        <!-- <td><a href="" data-type="text" data-abc="true" data-pk="<?php echo $row['deviceId']; ?>"><?php echo $row["functionData"]; ?></a></td> -->
                        <td data-type="text" data-pk="<?php echo $row['deviceId']; ?>" data-abc="true"><?php echo $row["functionData"]; ?></td>
                    
                        </tr>

                <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade drop-shadow" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h2>Function</h2>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button> 
                <!-- <h4 class="modal-title">Notification</h4>                                                              -->
            </div> 
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="update.php" id="save-form">
                    <div class="col-md-10 m-auto">
                        <div class="form group">
                            <label for="functionData"></label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="functionData" id="functionData">
                            <!-- <input class="modalTextinput form-control" type="text" name="deviceId" id="deviceId" > -->
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div> 
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <!-- <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>    -->
                    <button type="button" id="save-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>                               
                                
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>                                                                       
    </div>  
</div>
```

This is my jquery to load the modal, which is does.  The problem is it does not load the cell data.

```
$('#scandata').on('click-cell.bs.table', function (field, value, row, $el) {
  if ( value == "functionData") {
 
    // alert($el.deviceId+"-"+$el.functionData);
    let deviceId = $el.deviceId;
    let functionData = $el.functionData;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'getFunctionData.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {deviceId: deviceId, functionData:functionData},
      success: function(response){ 
        // Add response in modal body
        $('.functionData').val(response.functionData);
        $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
      }
    });
  }
});
```

And my getFunctionData.php:

```
if ( $stmt = $connection->prepare($functionQuery)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $deviceId);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($functionData);
}

echo json_encode($functionData);
```

Comment: did you check `tools ` -> `network`  or `console` for errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your input field has the id="functionData", but you try to address the input field with a non existent class. change $('.functionData') to $('#functionData').

`$('.functionData').val(...)` is for classes `<input class="functionData" ...`

`$('#functionData').val(...)` is for id's `<input id="functionData" ...`

Comment: Excellent catch.  I changed it, but I still cannot get the returned value (from getFunctionData.php) to appear in the modal field.

Comment: Okay. Please check the response with `success: function(response){ console.log(response.functionData); ... }` and your browser dev-tools, whether that is also the string as expected.

Comment: The console.log entry shows "undefined" even when there is an entry in the column data. However, when I view the XHR response, I see the appropriate data there (such as "DNS Server").

Comment: I'm not sure about javascript. i think it is: `console.log(response)` and `$('#functionData').val(response);`

Comment: Great.  That gives me a response in the modal.  I think JSON.parse(response) and I"m good to go.  I need to pass two variables back but I think I should start a separate question for that.  Thanks for your help.